# How to indent php delimiter in php-mode?

Tags: indentation, php-mode

php-mode is not indenting delimiter:

```
<?php
// Not indenting PHP delimiter

if (true) {
    echo 'foo';
}
```

How to indent delimiter?

```
<?php
    // Indenting PHP delimiter

    if (true) {
        echo 'foo';
    }
```

I tryed:

```
(defun my-php-indent-setup ()
  (c-set-offset 'cpp-macro '+))

(add-hook 'php-mode-hook 'my-php-indent-setup)
```

But does nothing, and if I do it manually `C-c C-o RET cpp-macro RET + RET` it doesn't exactly do what I expected. I also tryed `topmost-intro` instead `cpp-macro`, but neither do what I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
(defun my-php-indent-setup ()
    (c-set-offset 'topmost-intro '+) ; Does not affect <?php (but affects ?>)
    (c-set-offset 'inclass 0))       ; Gets the inside of class{} back to normal

(add-hook 'php-mode-hook 'my-php-indent-setup)
```

Note that the closing tag `?>` will not be indented in the same level as `<?php` does, for example:

```
<?php
    // Indenting PHP delimiter

    if (true) {
        echo 'foo';
    }

    ?>
```

Anyways some PHP coding standards recommend to not include `?>` in pure PHP files.